Migrating to spring 3.3.0+ version, causes issues with wiremock
im trying to update from spring-boot 3.1.9 to 3.3.1. When i update  the version, tests using wiremock start failing.
I read about the standalone version,
and have updated my gradle script accordingly from "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:3.0.0-beta-10" to     "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:3.0.1"
However i also have a spring "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner:4.1.2") dependency and that one in turn uses     wiremock-jre8-standalone
i have tried to manually remove that one like so
  testImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:3.0.1")
  testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner:4.1.2") {
        exclude(group = "com.github.tomakehurst", module = "wiremock-jre8-standalone")
    }

and force the new one to be used
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:3.0.1")
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        exclude(group = "com.github.tomakehurst", module = "wiremock-jre8-standalone")
    }

however it didn't help and im still stuck with the same exception:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer.<init>(boolean)'
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.init(WireMockConfiguration.java:107)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:219)
... 29 more

i have tried the advice from here removing the dependency and keeping only the one from spring-cloud keeping only the com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.35.1
as a transitive dependency in org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner:4.1.4 however I still have the same issue.
any clues would be greatly appriciated!

If you are upgrading Spring Boot you also need to upgrade Spring Cloud those versions are tied together. Next to that I would suggest to use the org.wiremock dependency which is newer (version 3.8) you are using an older version.

It is a shame that Spring Cloud ships such an old version of WireMock.  I don't know how much change this will require to your tests but it might be worth you looking at the wiremock jetty 12 dependency that should work with Spring 3.x.x without any issues - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wiremock/wiremock-jetty12

There are some examples of the jetty 12 dependency here - https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-examples/tree/main/spring-boot/spring-boot-3
